# printf not working outside a function with a pointer to struct

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

Everything is heavily simplified from my project which is why there is only one int in the struct here for example.

In the .h :

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
}Jeux;
```

And in the .c:

```
void filesLoad(Jeux* tJeux){
    (...)
    tJeux = malloc(sizeof(Jeux));
    fscanf(flot,"%d%*[^\n]\n", &tJeux->id);
    printf("id stocked: %d\n", tJeux->id);
    fclose(flot);
}

int main(void){
Jeux* tJeux;
filesLoad(tJeux);
printf("id stocké: %d\n", tJeux->id);
}
```

Now the problem: For some reason, the printf in the function works perfectly fine but the one outside filesLoad crashes my program, help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reassigning `tJeux` within the function to a freshly allocated piece of memory, but that change is never propagated back up to `main`.

Instead maybe make `filesLoad` write *into* a pre-allocated object:

```
typedef struct { int id; } Jeux;

void filesLoad(Jeux *tJeux) {
  // ...
  fscanf(flot, "%d%*[^\n]\n", &tJeux->id);
}

int main(void) {
  Jeux *tJeux = malloc(sizeof(Jeux));
  filesLoad(tJeux); // Load a file into `tJeux`
  printf("id stocké: %d\n", tJeux->id);
}
```

Additionally, you could have a function that allocates and loads a `Jeux` (but do remember it will then be the caller's responsibility to eventually free the Jeux):

```
typedef struct { int id; } Jeux;

void filesLoad(Jeux *tJeux) {
  // ...
  fscanf(flot, "%d%*[^\n]\n", &tJeux->id);
}

Jeux* allocateAndFilesLoad() {
  Jeux* tJeux = malloc(sizeof(Jeux));
  filesLoad(tJeux);
  return tJeux;
}

int main(void) {
  Jeux *tJeux = allocateAndFilesLoad();
  printf("id stocké: %d\n", tJeux->id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change something in a function that exists *outside* of that function, you emulate pass-by-reference by passing in a pointer to it and dereferencing that pointer:

```
void change(int *pVal) { *pVal = 42; }
int val = 7;
change(&val);
// Now it's 42.
```

That's no different to changing a pointer but you have to pass in a *pointer* to the pointer, something like:

```
void filesLoad(Jeux **ptJeux){
    *ptJeux = malloc(sizeof(Jeux));
    fscanf(flot,"%d%*[^\n]\n", &(*ptJeux)->id);
    printf("id stocked: %d\n", (*ptJeux)->id);
    fclose(flot);
}

int main(void){
    Jeux* tJeux;
    filesLoad(&tJeux);
    :
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to change the prototype of `filesLoad` then you can use any of the below methods.

If you are not allowed to change, then the way suggested by @AKX is the way to go.

Method 1.
return the address of allocated memory ( call by value )

```
Jeux* filesLoad(void) {
    (...)
    Jeux* tJeux = malloc(sizeof(Jeux));
    fscanf(flot,"%d%*[^\n]\n", &tJeux->id);
    printf("id stocked: %d\n", tJeux->id);
    fclose(flot);
    return tJeux;
}

int main(void){
    Jeux* tJeux;
    tJeux = filesLoad(tJeux);
    printf("id stocké: %d\n", tJeux->id);
}
```

Method 2:
pass the address ( call by reference )

```
void filesLoad(Jeux** tJeux){
    (...)
    *tJeux = malloc(sizeof(Jeux));
    fscanf(flot,"%d%*[^\n]\n", &((*tJeux)->id));
    printf("id stocked: %d\n", *tJeux->id);
    fclose(flot);
}

int main(void){
    Jeux* tJeux;
    filesLoad(&tJeux);
    printf("id stocké: %d\n", tJeux->id);
}
```

Comment: Why would `Jeux* filesLoad(Jeux* tJeux)` accept a `tJeux` pointer if it's just going to throw it away?

Comment: @AKX, could you please elaborate a bit i couldn't get your comment.

Comment: The first thing your suggested `filesLoad` function does is reassign a new value to `tJeux`, so why even bother accepting an argument?

Comment: Ah, got you!! `filesLoad` can be `Jeux* filesLoad(void)` for Method1 ,right? I was hurrying for something else then dint give much thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be sth. like:

```c
void filesLoad(Jeux* tJeux)
{
    (...)
    fscanf(flot,"%d%*[^\n]\n", &tJeux->id);
    printf("id stocked: %d\n", tJeux->id);
    fclose(flot);
}

int main(void)
{
   Jeux* tJeux = (Jeux*) malloc(sizeof(Jeux));
   filesLoad(tJeux);
   printf("id stocké: %d\n", tJeux->id);
}
```

It should be done in the main, because `tJeux` was allocated in `filesLoad` the stack of the function, and it would be removed after returning from the function.

EDIT: sorry, I don't have much experience with giving answers in stack overflow. Thank you for the critics.

Comment: What did you change, and why does that help? An answer without explanation is far less helpful than one with.

Comment: I allocated the struct in the main not in the function.

Comment: I edited my answer. Thank you for your critics @underscore_d. I didn't think about giving an explanation first :O